# How to access v-data-table current page and items-per-page to calculate rows index?

Tags: vuetify.js

How to get `v-data-table` current page value and selected `items-per-page` value in order to use it in the template of my component ?

I need to access these two variable to calculate and display rows index.

```
<v-data-table
  dense
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :footer-props="{
    'items-per-page-options': [10, 50, 100]
  }"
  :items-per-page="50"
>
  <template #item.index="{ index }">
    <div class="text-caption text-right">
      {{ index + 1 }}.
    </div>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`pagination` event](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events-pagination) that is fired every time something has changed regarding the pagination of the table. The payload contains the current `page` and `itemsPerPage`.